# let $x= (1,-2, 2), y=(3, 4, -2)$ be position vectors. $x,y$,origin form parallelogram with $4^{\text{th}}$ point $z$ lying opposite origin.

Tags: vectors

For this question we need to find $z$. I found vector $XY$ as I thought that would give me position of z however that wasn't correct. I am unsure on what to do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the parallelogram law of vector addition,

$$\vec{z} = \vec{x} + \vec{y}$$

Comment: Oh right, I never knew there was such a law. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Just wondering, if it was a rectangle rather than parallelogram, would you find  vector XY?

Comment: No. Rectangle is also a parallelogram. So I'd do the same thing.